# Running apps and widget in the same process?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have the following:

1. an app called app1
2. an optional app called app2 (same userid and certificate as app1. it has extra permissions for 'pro' functionality and users can choose if to install it or not).
3. A widget provider

Is it possible to run all the three in the same JVM instance such that I can share global variables and synchronization locks between them?

I searched and looked around but am still puzzled whether the widget provider always runs within the same JVM instance as the app or not. Any clarification or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I searched and looked around but am still puzzled whether the widget provider always runs within the same JVM instance as the app or not.

An app widget will run in the same process as the rest of the components in the APK in which the app widget provider is defined.

> an optional app called app2 (same userid and certificate as app1. it has extra permissions for 'pro' functionality and users can choose if to install it or not).

This is not recommended. `android:sharedUserId` is a fragile construct, designed mostly for use by firmware apps. Basically you can *never* change this value without locking out all your installed users from their existing app files (e.g., databases).

> Is it possible to run all the three in the same JVM instance such that I can share global variables and synchronization locks between them?

You won't readily be able to share static data members (a.k.a., global variables) between them, as each APK will have its own classloader.

Comment: Thanks commonsware. Does the last comment (different class loader) applies also to a widget provider and a single app?

Comment: @user1139880: No, because they are in the same APK.

Answer (score 1):

> "An app widget will run in the same process "

This is not correct. App widgets run in Home screen process. Or in the work not in user process. That's the one reason you need to use remote views to access and update your app widget views.